# Ubuntu 19.04 word prediction / suggestion / autocomplete

Tags: 19.04, text, auto-completion

I have moved to Ubuntu 19.04 from Windows 10 and I noticed that Ubuntu predicts the words I am about to type, based on my previously typed words. I liked it at first, but now, a few  months later, I hate it. It's laggy in some web or desktop apps (e.g. VSCode).

This feature was there since I installed Ubuntu, it's not an extra app that I have downloaded.

How can I disable it?

As you can see in this screenshot, I only wrote "under" but Ubuntu is sure that I will write "understand".

[image: demo of word prediction]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshoot ?

Comment: provided screenshot

Comment: I am not sure what software is doing your auto completion since it seem that there is no auto completion tool provided on Ubuntu by default, maybe you have install something like autokey https://github.com/autokey/autokey

Comment: What browser are you using there? Firefox? Chrome? Something else? I'm pretty sure there isn't such word prediction by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: I mentioned that this thing happens not only in web. Visual Studio Code is a desktop application. I am using Opera.

Comment: I know that I haven't downloaded extra software, but I can tell that when I was installing Ubuntu, I chose "all recommended software" or something like that, don't remember. (so there was a choice like "install minimal software or all recommended?", I have chosen second one.)

Comment: It's not autokey I guess. I have typed "autokey" in cli, it suggested me to download it with `sudo apt install autokey-gtk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm Russian, I quite often switch layout from RU to EN, and I have downloaded Xneur to automate this. I don't ever think that this thing do word prediction. I have killed it. Now I can type without predictions. Thank you everyone.